# How to set devise mails sender name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I am using rails devise gem. Devise sends cofirmation email to new users. Actionmailer is configured to use my gmail account to send emails.

The email is sent by sender: "no-reply@myapp.com" which is my **actionmailer** global username configuration.

I want to set sender to include my name "**Mahmoud Khaled** no-reply@myapp.com"

And for sure I can't update actionmailer username configration to include name because it should be only GMAIL username.

Any help how can i set devise from parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

edit your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file - it's pretty near the top, `config.mailer_sender`

Comment: config/initializers/devise.rb is for global settings, but what about using different devise accounts, like instructor, student, user .. etc ? please check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586646/rails-3-devise-how-to-set-sender-name-from-model

Answer (score 5):

If you are using stmp of gmail, you cannot change the address of sender.

Google prohibited changing the address of sender.

Comment: I'm using Google as the sender but I changed the name without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

For me this one `Mahmoud Khaled no-reply@myapp.com` is working, by emails go directly to spam folder (gmail,yahoo,hotmail)