# How to set Devise sender name for email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Although [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674879/how-to-set-devise-mails-sender-name) doesn't say much, I figured you set the sender name in the Devise intializer like this:

```
app/config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "'MySite' <no-reply@mysite.com>"
end
```

But this didn't work for me.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is it:

```
config.mailer_sender = '"Example.com" <your@site.com>'
```

Comment: Is there any change other than the different quotes (`'`vs. `"`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use escaped characters like this:

```
config.mailer_sender = "\"Support Desk\" <support@site.com>"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this for devise, heroku and mandrill: and you're setting the email address as an environment variable you'll need to do it like so (I found out the hard way when the above email format above broke our sign up process, let my pain be your gain :)

```
Label:  Value:
EMAIL   Example.com <no-reply@example.com>
```

No ' or " required.