# Devise SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi this is my first attempt to send emails through my app, so if I didn`t post any value info please leave a comment and I will add it.

As far as I get, is to this error: `SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)`

This are my production.rb settings:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'my-app.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    port:           587,
    address:        'smtp.maigun.org',
    domain:         ENV['ms_domain'], #Domain name
    user_name:      ENV['ms_username'], #Default SMTP Login
    password:       ENV['ms_pass'], #Default Password

    authentication: :plain
  }
```

I have also set:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'Kazik <mymail@gmail.com>'
```

As far as I understand, settings in my production.rb file are the settings that Devise should use, to send emails. And mailer_sender setting is just used as an field for replay to field.

So probably the problem lies in the ActionMailer settings

I will be glad for any explanations.

Comment: `'smtp.maigun.org',` should that be `'smtp.mailgun.org'`?

Comment: It helped :), to get me to another error :( 'Net::SMTPSyntaxError (501 5.5.4 Invalid argument' any idea ?

Comment: Not without more info, no. An easy guess would be that the environment variables are not set correctly, or that `mailer_sender` only accepts an email address, nothing more.

Comment: What info would you need? As for the env variables they were copied from mailu server details.

Comment: Did you try removing the `domain` part in the settings?

Comment: I have tried change the mailer sender to: '"Kazik" <kazik@wp.pl>' following this question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712916/how-to-setup-devise-sender-name-for-email and I still get Net error, after this I have changed removed the 'domain' from smtp settings and now I`m getting `Net::SMTPFatalError (550 5.7.1 Relaying denied`